# Как по очереди вывести элементы из 2 списков?

Tags: list, telebot, бот, telegram

Создаю тг-бота. Требуется, чтобы он выводил элементы списка "по очереди". По типу:

> Бот: "Элемент 1 из Списка 1"
> "Элемент 1 из Списка 2"
> "Элемент 2 из Списка 2"

И так далее.

В одном списке значения типа int, в другом строчки

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вот, что требуется:" + "\n".join(str(x) for x in list1) + " ".join(list2))`

По этому коду бот выводит таким образом:

> Бот: "Элемент 1 из Списка 1"
> "Элемент 2 из Списка 1"
> "Элемент 1 из Списка 2"
> "Элемент 2 из Списка 2"

То есть, он сперва выводит все значения из первого списка, а после все значения из второго списка.

Возможно ли реализовать вывод элементов списка по очереди?

Comment: То есть сделать перебор всех 1 элементов в списках а потом уже вторых?

Comment: Нет, требуется выведение элементов из списков по очереди, то есть. 1 элемент из Списка 1, потом 1 элемент из Списка 2, после 2 элемент из Списка 1. И Так далее))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) из двух списков делает один список пар. Пары склеиваются в строки, которые склеиваются в текст сообщения:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
    'Вот, что требуется:\n' +
    '\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(map(str, list1), list2)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Это вполне возможно:

```
list1 = [1, 2]  # int
list2 = ['"Элемент 1 из Списка 2"', '"Элемент 2 из Списка 2"',
         '"Элемент 3 из Списка 2"']  # str
print(" ".join([(str(list1[i] if i < len(list1) else '') + " " +
                 (list2[i] if i < len(list2) else '')).strip()
                for i in range(max(len(list1), len(list2)))]))
```

> 1 "Элемент 1 из Списка 2" 2 "Элемент 2 из Списка 2" "Элемент 3 из Списка 2"

В данном случае:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вот, что требуется: " +
                 " ".join([(str(list1[i] if i < len(list1) else '') + " " +
                            (list2[i] if i < len(list2) else '')).strip()
                           for i in range(max(len(list1), len(list2)))]))
```